# How to convert value from sklearn MinMaxScaler() back to real value?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras

I use sklearn MinMaxScaler() like this.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

sc = MinMaxScaler()

train_sc = sc.fit_transform(train)
test_sc = sc.transform(test)
```

It change data to range 0-1 . After I predict already it still be value 0-1. How to convert back to real value ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`inverse_transform()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform) on the output predicted data.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

data = [[-1, 2], [-0.5, 6], [0, 10], [1, 18]]
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(data)    

print(scaler.transform([[2, 2]]))
Out>>> [[ 1.5  0. ]]

// This is what you need
print(scaler.inverse_transform([[ 1.5  0. ]]))
Out>>> [[ 2.0  2.0]]
```